# saber dónde/adónde está escondido

Tags: pronombres

I heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Pero sí sabes adónde está escondido, cierto?

As "saber" is not a verb of movement, shouldn't "dónde" be used instead of "adónde" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction

> Sabes adónde está escondido

is wrong according to [the DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wFbvYdpRYD6ESQMlOO), see the second point:

> 2. En el español actual debe evitarse el uso arcaico de *adónde*, *a dónde* sin valor de movimiento: «Me preguntó Carlitos, mi hijo, que adónde había estado» (LpzPáez Herlinda [Méx. 1993])

This use seems to have been commom in the past and not be correct now. The correct sentence in your case would be

> Pero sí sabes dónde está escondido, cierto?

Comment: As the line is said by a Colonel in the TV series, I guess it is a common Spanish error, even for native speakers?

Comment: @Alan yes, it is not uncommon to hear *adónde* implying movement. It is not common in my area, and it does sound "funny" to me, but it happens more in other areas. (Then again, *afuera* without movement also sounds funny to me but it is accepted by RAE).

Comment: @Alan (I meant "it is not uncommon to hear *adónde* without implying movement")